# problem of syntax in where clause when 2 columns are equal?

Tags: laravel, where-clause

I have a filter on a form before displaying a list.
If the filter 'filter_parisetat' = 2, i set the where clause like this :

```
 $query = $query->where('gri_nb_matchs','gri_nb_matchs_pec');
```

I want to select all the rows of my Grille table where 'gri_nb_matchs' equals 'gri_nb_matchs_pec'
but it doesn't work..nothing is selected (and of course in my table I have 10 in each columns for these 2 fields

The other Where conditions in case 1 is equal to

```
$query = $query->where('gri_nb_matchs','>','gri_nb_matchs_pec');
```

I should retrieve 0  rows, but here I retrieve all the rows..
it works upside down...

In My table, the 2 fields are described like this :
    11  gri_nb_matchs   tinyint(3)      UNSIGNED
    12  gri_nb_matchs_pec   tinyint(3)      UNSIGNED

In MySql, whenI write the query, results are correct..

What went wrong ?
Thanks a lot
Thierry

Comment: You misspelled the `variable`,  change `->where('gri_nb_matchs','gri_nb_matchs_pec');` to `->where('gri_nb_matchs', $gri_nb_matchs_pec);`,  here `$gri_nb_matchs_pec` is a variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this statement:

```
$query = $query->where('gri_nb_matchs','>','gri_nb_matchs_pec');
```

It seems you are comparing the field gri_nb_matchs to the string value 'gri_nb_matchs_pec', not the column named gri_nb_matchs_pec.  In order to achieve this you have to use a raw query as so:

```
$query = $query->where('gri_nb_matchs','>',DB::raw('gri_nb_matchs_pec'));
```

or

```
$query = $query->whereRaw('gri_nb_matchs > gri_nb_matchs_pec');
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help !! , I had just found the solution in another post..But whereraw was not mentioned ..Impossible to find this info int the Laravel doc..Do you have an official page to find this kind of info ? Many thanks, you saved me :-)